# Compute Canvas3D preferredSize to fit content

Tags: java, java-3d

I have a Java3D application where I'm displaying 3d models in a Canvas3D. My Canvas3D is in a scrollpane and for the moment the Canvas3D has a default 800x600 preferredSize, which fits most models but some are cropped.

Is there a simple way to compute the preferredSize of the Canvas3D so it is big enough to fit the whole model?

Thank you

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/q/9020783 doesn't do the computation automatically. But with a bit of geometry it could be expanded to fit your needs.

Comment: And this http://www.daltonfilho.com/articles/java3d/SimpleModelView.html/SimpleModelView.html is an example on how to set the actual canvas size. Be aware that it loads an hard-coded obj-file, you will have to change this before you can run it.

Comment: 404 for the second link, can i get it somewhere else? Im very interested in this

Comment: That's the internet, sorry. The link worked 2 days ago. Will see how I can retrieve the essential parts.